# React Router with other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have one problem that I can not understand. I am totally a beginner in ReactJS so I hope you will help me. I made Navigation with React Router and it works, but when I start to render all other components in App.js nothings happened. When I am routing through the navigation bar it is rendering, but on scroll, nothing happened.

This is my App.js without rendering other components that work normally, but when I add something like ,  it is the same without scroll.

my code :

```
const App = () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Router>
                <Topbar />

                <About />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                  <Route path="/service" component={Service} />
                  <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
                  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
               </Switch>
            </Router>
           </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a redirect

1/ `import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';`

2/ Change your Home route to `<Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />`

3/ Add the redirect (It must be the last route)

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Redirect to="/home" />
</Route>
```

**Example :**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Service from './Service';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';
import Contact from './Contact';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/service" component={Service} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />

        {/* Redirect */}
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you want to check a demo : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z6hfxq)